# odoo and network print

Tags: networking, printing, odoo

Newbie guy trying to install POS on Odoo.

I am unable to get an answer to this question anywhere.... even in odoo forum.

I just need to know its possibility... and pointers if possible :)

Can I use an epson TM-T20II (networked) and print directly to it by IP? running Odoo POS on a linux system remotely (with ports opened on router)!

The possibility of using 2 printers (kitchen and main POS) on the same system?

Any vantage on the newer Epson TM-T88VI on network print?

regards

Comment: tks for your answer, thats exactly what I need prior of investing on network printers :) because if its possible I will reach it sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use any of receipt printer remotely, also you can use multiple pinter i.e. for kitchen, for main POS